# Try-Catch sum two numbers

Tags: exception, try-catch

I'm working on Exception Handling and making a new Java Project.Program waits for user type 2 numbers from keyboard. If user types two integer numbers it'll sum these numbers. If user doesn't type numbers program will print 'Type numbers!' on screen. Here's What I Tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    System.out.println("Type two numbers");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        a = scan.nextInt();
        b = scan.nextInt();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Type number!");
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Exact question is if user doesn't type integer values an error has occur when we want to sum these numbers.So I didn't write sum operation

Comment: ok, but what is your question? are you asking how to print the sum of 2 numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below. It should work as you expect:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Type two numbers");
    sum();
}

private static void sum(){
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        a = scan.nextInt();
        b = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(a+b);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Type numbers in correct format!");
        sum();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much.Why did you write private?It works if there's no keyword in front of static void sum

Comment: Yes, private is optional. It won't make much difference to actual question

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Errors {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("Enter an Integer Value for addition:-");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int user = 0;
        int user2 = 0;
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter value A");
            user = sc.nextInt();
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter value B");
                user2 = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println(user+user2);
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.err.println("Please enter an Integer Value");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("Please enter an Integer value ");
        }

    }
}
```